# setMethods is deprecated and will be removed in future releases

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

I am using the function setMethods, it is still working, however I received the above message on the console. I am wondering what should be the new approach?.

It is being used to spy on a method and then see if it was called with the mocked parameters, here is the code:

```
const spyGenerateCalendar = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'generateCalendar');
const spyAxiosRequest = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');

// setting methods for spying
wrapper.setMethods({generateCalendar: spyGenerateCalendar});

wrapper.vm.generateCalendar();

// Expecting calls
expect(spyGenerateCalendar).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(spyAxiosRequest).toBeCalledWith(axiosRequestURL, axiosRequestParams);
```

Answer (score 7):

It is unneeded. I am already spying on the method "generateCalendar" on the line:

```
  const spyGenerateCalendar = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'generateCalendar');
```

So If the line `wrapper.setMethods({generateCalendar: spyGenerateCalendar});` is removed. The result will be the same, so `expect(spyGenerateCalendar).toHaveBeenCalled();` will be true